# if y else if no funciona PHP

Tags: php, condiciones

Estoy queriendo crear un sistema de pagos.

La idea es que en una lista de alumnos de una escuela, aparezcan ciertos datos de la BD, y al final las acciones.

Cada clase que toma el alumno, tiene su respectivo id, cuyo valor está en la tabla de alumnos.
Lo mismo sucede con los estados de pago. Tengo una tabla con los diferentes estados de pago, y su respectivo id, cuyo valor está en la tabla de alumnos.
Respecto de los id, tengo los siguientes datos:
id= 1, estado = PENDIENTE
id= 2, estado = PAGADO

Lo que hice básicamente es listar todos los datos de los alumnos, y en la parte del estado de pago, listar los nombres.

Lo que quiero hacer es agregar un campo en la interfaz con un botón que diga "PAGAR"si está pendiente, es decir, si el el pago de la tabla alumnos tiene el "1", y luego un simple texto que diga "SIN ACCIONES" si el mismo estado tiene el valor "2".

El script que diseñé es el siguiente:

```
<?php
      $estadoPago = "SELECT * FROM estado_pagos WHERE id = $alumnos[pago]";
      $consultaPago = $con->query($estadoPago);
      if ($consultaPago == 1) {
           echo '<a href="php/pagar.php" type="button" class="btn btn-success text-white">PAGAR</a>';
      }elseif ($consultaPago == 2){
           echo 'SIN ACCIONES';
           }
 ?>
```

El problema es que el script no funciona y aparece el botón "PAGAR" en cualquiera de ambos casos, y la idea final es agregar otras opciones con otros id en la tabla de los estados.

Espero se entienda, gracias.

Comment: que es lo que devuelve $con->query? no devuelve los datos de la consulta? no querras ir a ver un campo den particular de $consultapago?

Comment: Deberias preguntar asi: if $consultaPago['id'] == '1'. Suponiendo que la tabla estado_pagos tenga la columna "id". En todo caso reemplaza 'id' . Pero, no sé,  si solo son dos valores ¿por qué no preguntas directamente si $alumno[pago] == '1'?

Answer (score 0):

El `if` que indicas, en realidad si funciona.
Ya que el restultado de la consulta se ejecuta, y al ejecutar la respuesta de esta sera `true` osea cae dentro de la sentencia que realizas.

```
$estadoPago = "SELECT * FROM estado_pagos WHERE id = $alumnos[pago]";
$consultaPago = $con->query($estadoPago);
```

El valor de `$consultaPago` será `true` si es que puede realizar o no la consulta, independiente si retorne 0 o 1 o mas registros.

Entonces, lo que habria que hacer sería consultar si es que tiene un pago asociado, comprobando cuantos registros trae el resultado de tu consulta

```
$estadoPago = "SELECT * FROM estado_pagos WHERE id = $alumnos[pago]";
$consultaPago = $con->query($estadoPago);

if($consultaPago->num_rows >= 1){
   echo '<a href="php/pagar.php" type="button" class="btn btn-success text-white">PAGAR</a>';
} else {
   echo 'SIN ACCIONES';
}
```

Ahora bien, como la consulta es por el estado del pago tendras que consultar por la columna que necesitas.

```
$estadoPago = "SELECT * FROM estado_pagos WHERE id = $alumnos[pago]";
$consultaPago = $con->query($estadoPago);
$fila = $consultaPago->fetch_assoc();

if($fila['id'] == 1){
   echo '<a href="php/pagar.php" type="button" class="btn btn-success text-white">PAGAR</a>';
} else {
   echo 'SIN ACCIONES';
}
```

`$fila = $consultaPago->fetch_assoc();` con esto recuperaras el resultado de tu consulta.